# Ionic 2 Post Request with php codeigniter api

Tags: php, codeigniter, typescript, ionic2, angular2-services

I am using ionic 2 Http.post method with php API. My problem is i am getting **Disallowed Key Characters**. error on client side. While i figured out in postman that this error arrives when i select form-data option from postman it says "Disallowed Key Characters." in response.
 [image: postman]

As well as when i select x-www-form-urlencoded option i get the response and my info updated successfully in mySQL server.

Here is my .ts file code:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:','*');
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  let postData = { 
                  FirstName:"testname", 
                  LastName:"testlastname",
                  PhoneNumber:"12345", 
                  EmailAddress:"test@gmail.com", 
                  InsertedBy:"21" 
                 };
this.http.post('http://localhost:889/api/user/users.json', JSON.stringify(postData),options)
  .subscribe((data) => {
            //var data = res.json();
  console.log(data);
 }
```

I think there is a problem while passing header. Somebody guide me where i am doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot of error:
[image]

This api works fine when selecting x-www-form-urlencoded with postman:
[image]

Comment: Share ur issue screenshot here .

Comment: Screenshot of error?

Comment: yes because i am not able to understand what type of issue u r facing . and this is backend issue so ask ur backend team to fix this issue .

Comment: This is not a backend error because when i pass post parameters it work fine!

Comment: Please check my question i've added screenshots

Comment: API does not give cors issue on postman .

Comment: Is this a cors issue?? ... My api contains these headers:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');